After a few rotations of upgrades absolute paths to styles stopped working (Angular 15-17)
I have received an error during serve and build my angular project:

Yesterday I tried to upgrade my angular version from 15 to 17 in another branch where received the same message. So I did a few kills/reinstallations of node-modules and package-lock. And now it is the same for my current branch. If I click on a file in an error (src/etc/etc) my ide will open the file without issues so they exist exacly where the path points.
If I change all the paths to relative ones it will work, but why, even on a branch with no upgrades I receive this warning and how to fix it so I can use absolute path?
Also strange fact is that, I receive only a few errors of this kind. Like 2 or 3 paths with this error at first. I fix them without killing serve process and it will pass at some point.
Then, if I stop it and retry serve, I will receieve another portion of incorrect paths.
Thanks in advance.
My tsconfig baseUrl is
"baseUrl": "src"

My stylePreprocessorOptions are:
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": ["src/styles"]
 }


The only problem I see is that, you have configured to include the paths "src/styles" but you are using the styles present in the "src/assets" folder so it's not configured for absolute imports at all, you can move it inside the styles folder for it to work or add the assets path to the includePaths array.

I have tryied to use "stylePreprocessorOptions": {"includePaths": ["src"] } to include both paths, but it didn't help.

UPD: adding another path to options also didn't work.

@KarinaKoroleva create a new dummy project with same version of angular and check if it works there, if it does you have a reference to compare with your code and identity the problem

thanks... This is gonna definately take some time... ;(
